# Posts won't change size from within app

Tags: javascript, android, variables, react-native, react-native-flatlist

**Problem**
I am creating a simple app with React Native and firebase which will let users post to firebase, and the app will render all of the posts. I am making the first alpha version of the app, and I am making the user manually adjust the post size to fit there screen via a text input box. I have one prototype post that is stored on the phone for testing, and when you change the variable in the text input the prototype post will change, but not the real posts (in the flatlist). I would love some help getting the posts in the FlatList to change size when you edit the postWidth variable. Thanks!

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API-key",
  authDomain: "candidtwo.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://candidtwo.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "candidtwo.appspot.com",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var fontLoaded = false;

var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts');



var newPostRef = ref.push();

var postWidth = 350;

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };



  componentDidMount() {
      Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf': require('./JosefinSans-Regular.ttf'),
      });
 }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { postInput: ""}
 }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getItems();
 }

  getItems(){
    var items = [];
    var query = ref.orderByKey();
    query.once ('value', (snap) => {
      snap.forEach ( (child) => {       
       items.push(
        child.val().content
        );     
      });
    items.reverse();
    }).then(() => {
        this.setState({firebaseItems: items});
    });
 }


 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
            title="Get started anonymously!"
            color="#fe8200"
            accessibilityLabel="Run the app"
          />
        </View>

        {this.state.fontLoaded ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Whats on your mind? Create a post!
            </Text>  

            <TextInput
                 style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                 onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
                 value={this.state.postInput}    
             />


    <Button
      style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}
      onPress={() => {
        newPostRef.set({ content:this.state.postInput });
        this.setState({ postInput: "Your post was succsesfully uploaded! :)" })    
      }}               
      title="   +   "
      color="#fe8200"
    />

<View style={{width: 2500, height: 4, backgroundColor: '#a9a9a9'}}></View>


            <ScrollView>

<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Adjust the size of posts:
            </Text>  

            <TextInput
                 style={{height:40, width: 100, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                 onChangeText={(postWidth)=>this.setState({postWidth})}
                 value={this.state.postWidth}    
             />



               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: parseInt(this.state.postWidth), height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',    borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight:10}} >
         <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    Prototype Post: Why do android phones have higher inital quality than apple phones, but apple phones have a more consistent amount of quality throughout their years?
                </Text>
            </View>
               <View style={{width: parseInt(this.state.postWidth), height: 40, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#147aa8', flexDirection: 'row',paddingLeft:5}} >
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/unlove.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                    3
                    </Text>
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/undislike.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                    1
                    </Text>
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/comments.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', paddingRight: 5, paddingTop:5}}>
                    8
                    </Text>
        </View>
    <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />


     <FlatList
        data = {this.state.firebaseItems}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
     <View>
                <View style={{width: parseInt(this.state.postWidth), height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight:10}}>
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf', fontSize: 22, color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                        { item }
                    </Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{width: parseInt(this.state.postWidth), height: 40, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#147aa8', flexDirection: 'row',paddingLeft:5}} >

                </View>
                <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
            </View>
  }
    />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>) : (null) }
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should move your `postWidth` in your initial state declaration like this...

```
state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
    postWidth = 350,
}
```

But that's probably not your problem. The next thing I might do is refactor to move all your `parseInt(this.state.postWidth)` above your return statement so that you can just use a single variable like so...

```
render() {
  let postWidth = parseInt(this.state.postWidth);
  return(
      <View style={{width: postWidth}} />
  );
}
```

I don't think that's going to solve your issue either, but those were the only things I could find to comment on. There's a lot going on in your render method (too much really), so maybe refactor to simplify it a bit and if these tips don't help, maybe refactoring it will shed some light.

I recommend trying something super simple first, like changing the width of a single, simple view. Then start adding more.

Good luck!